# Fixed Point Toolbox function fi substitution

Tags: matlab

I have a function to convert double to 16-bit value in Matlab, doing the following

```
a = fi(pi, 1, 16, 0)
```

Now I don't have the fixed point toolbox anymore so I cannot use function fi, I was wondering if there is an alternative way to achieve the same result?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Without the fi toolbox, you only have the base classes with 8,16,32 bit. The fourth parameter is basically scaling, you have to manually apply a bit shift by f